# How closure captures value type?

Tags: swift, closures

Please look at the following simple example:

```
var cl: (() -> ())! 
func foo() { 
    var x = 20
    cl = { 
      print(x)
    }

}
foo()
cl() // prints 20
```

Since `x` is an `Int` which is a value type and value types are "living" on the stack, once `foo` returns `x` should be vanished. Following the above mentioned line of reasoning `x` shouldn't exist when `cl` is called, but it still prints `20`. Can somebody explain how closure captures `x` in this case and keeps it in memory.
Please note that I'm not capturing `x` with capture list in this case. In case of capture list it is obvious since capturing value type with capture list just makes a copy of a captured value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can somebody explain how closure captures x in this case and keeps it in memory.

There isn't really a "how". That is what a closure *is*. It *does* capture `x` and keep it in memory. Basically, your `x` does not die when the local reference goes out of scope, because the closure has captured it and lives on; thus `x` still lives after `foo` has run, off in an invisible "closure capture" space belonging to this closure, for as long as the closure itself persists.

The ability of closures to do that is what makes a closure a closure.

A feature of this ability that your example doesn't get at is that the captured reference is still *writable* (because you said `var`). For example:

```
var cl: (() -> ())!
func foo() {
    var x = 20
    cl = {
      print(x)
      x += 1
    }

}
foo()
cl() // prints 20
cl() // prints 21
```

We are thus able to maintain state off in the closure-capture world.

Another thing to notice (I suppose you know this) is that if this had *not* been an automatic variable that goes out of scope, writing to it would affect the *original* — the reference is direct. Thus:

```
var cl: (() -> ())!
var x = 20
func foo() {
    cl = {
      print(x)
      x += 1
    }

}
foo()
cl() // prints 20
cl() // prints 21
print(x) // 22
```

Comment: I should add, if you _do_ use a capture list, yes you get a copy and it is not writable. It's just a value, not a capture.

Comment: thank you for such a great answer!  So, basically with an implicit capturing the  variable outside and inside of the closure is( roughly saying) the same variable! So, changing the variable outside of the closure changes it inside as well. And when you use explicit capturing(capture list) then the closure just maintains separate  non modifiable copy of that value. Right ? Sry for not very technical language, but I think you'll get the point)

Comment: Yes and I think you said it correctly. The capture list syntax is a way of saying, do _not_ use closure-capturing: just make a copy of the value _right now_. This is not often used, but it can be very handy when for some reason you do _not_ want the value that a thing _will have_ at the time the closure actually runs.